# Is there a function $f(x)$ and a constant $k$ so that $f(x-k) \neq O(f(x))$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Is there a function $f(x)$ and a constant $k$ so that $f(x-k) \neq O(f(x))$?

If it exist, what is the function, and if it doesn't, what is the proof to that?

My intuition is that big O refers to the worst case, meaning worst x, so no constant should have a significant effect on the time complexity, but I'm not sure at all, and I'm struggling to write it formally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Try a function that is decreasing fast when $x\to\infty$, e.g., $f(x):=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: edited thx.
@ChristianBlatter, but when it is infinite, what different a minus million to x makes?

Comment: $x$ can be big, but it is never infinite.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: if you answer, I will delete my answer.

Comment: I am puzzled by the downvote. The OP posted an answer, thereby showing their attempt, and where they went wrong. I have posted an answer, which follows Christian Blatter's comment, in hopes that the OP can see where their answer went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christian Blatter commented, let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
f(x-k)
&=e^{-(x-k)^2}\\
&=e^{2kx-k^2}e^{-x^2}\\
&=e^{2kx-k^2}f(x)
\end{align}
$$
That is, for $k\gt0$, $\frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}$ grows without bound as $x\to\infty$.

This means that $f(x-k)\not\in O(f(x))$.

Answer (score -1):

I got an idea, would love some verification:

I will prove that no such function exist and that for any function $f(x-k)=O(f(x))$.

- To prove that, I will use proof by contradiction assuming that there is a function that for $f(x-k)\neq O(f(x))$ does hold.
- There for $\lim \frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}=\infty$
- $\lim f(x)=\lim f(x-k)$
- If so, then $\lim \frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x-k)}{\lim f(x)}=1$, in contradiction to our assumption that $f(x-k)\neq O(f(x))\Leftrightarrow \lim \frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}=\infty$.
- There for indeed $f(x-k)=O(f(x))\blacksquare$

Comment: A problem is, you cannot write $\lim \frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x-k)}{\lim f(x)}=1$ if $\lim f(x-k) = \lim f(x) = \infty$ ...

Comment: yes, that's the whole point, i'm showing contradiction to prove the theorem. please read

Comment: but, the "theorem" is not true! The answer by robjohn provides a counterexample. What I wanted to point out above is that you cannot simplify $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ to $1$ because it is an indeterminate expression

Comment: Thx for the explanation and excuse my bad english, I see my mistake now. If I understand my mistake right, I assumed there is a lim to $f(x)$, when in the first place lim could be $\infty$ and there for I cannot $\frac{f(x-k)}{f(x)}$ because it is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and there for $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$ is a wrong expression?

Comment: That's correct. If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ tend to infinity then we cannot deduce anything for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. You can read a bit about these indeterminate forms (such as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Thank you very much!